# json parse with double backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have some json where the backslash is escaped like this

`"b\\ar"`

When I get the data back from fetch, the object looks like this:

`{ foo: "b\ar" }`

You can see that it has removed one of the backslashes

Problem is that if I search for a backslash in foo.bar it can't find one
because it thinks that it's an escape character called '\a'

Help please!!!

Comment: How exactly are you performing the search?

Comment: thats right - it has a backslash in it. it shouldn't be a escaped `a`.

Comment: I'm searching like this:
let obj = { foo: "b\ar" }
console.log(obj.foo.indexOf('\\'));
//-1
console.log(obj.foo.indexOf('\a'));
//1

Comment: Backslashes in strings in JavaScript have to be written as **two** backslashes. That's common to many other similar languages.

Comment: Thanks I understand that, but it was originally two slashes in the json string above, the parsing of the object removed one of them and now it thinks its an escape sequence called '\a'

Comment: Right, JSON is another example. The code in your comment above **does not** use doubled backslashes, so the single backslash will be ignored, unless the subsequent character is something that leads to an extended escape sequence of some kind.

Comment: That's what you see when you print out the parsed result. If you're going to try to re-create what the resulting object looks like, you have to double the backslashes.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean: it should be: let obj = "{ \"foo\": \"ba\\\\r\" }"
console.log(JSON.parse(obj).foo.indexOf('\\'))

Comment: Yes, if you want to apply `JSON.parse()`, though in plain JavaScript `let obj = {foo: "b\\ar"};` would give you an object with a backslash in the value of the "foo" property.